# Laravel Ajax Post request returns empty array

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, dropify

So for this assignment, I need to Add a progress bar for a Dropify uploader in a Laravel application. But it cannot seem to find the session according to the key, when I print out the session with the key, all it does is return an empty Array ( ).

My Form

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => route('admin.templates.store'), 'files' => true, 'id' => 'myForm')) }}
            <input type="hidden" value="myForm" name="{{ ini_get('session.upload_progress.name') }}">

                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('title') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    {{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required']) }}
                    {{ Form::label('name', 'Template name', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
                    <i class="bar"></i>
                    {{ $errors->first('name', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('title') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    {{ Form::textarea('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required', 'size' => '1x1']) }}
                    {{ Form::label('description', 'Template omschrijving', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
                    <i class="bar"></i>
                    {{ $errors->first('description', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('number_of_screens') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    {{ Form::number('number_of_screens', '1', ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required']) }}
                    {{ Form::label('number_of_screens', 'Aantal objecten', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
                    <i class="bar"></i>
                    {{ $errors->first('number_of_screens', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('templatefile') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    {{ Form::label('templateFile', 'Browse') }}
                    {{ Form::file('templateFile' , ['class' => 'dropify', 'data-allowed-file-extensions' => 'zip', 'required' => 'required']) }}
                    <div id="bar_blank">
                       <div id="bar_color"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="status"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="button-container">
                    {{ Form::submit('Uploaden', ['class' => 'button button-medium']) }}
                </div>

            {{ Form::close() }}
```

My Ajax request

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "{{route('admin.templates.uploadprogress')}}",
                        data: {
                            "data": $('#myForm').serialize(),
                            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                        },
                        success: function() {
                            console.log("Geodata sent");
                        }
                    });
```

My route

```
Route::post('/uploadprogress', 'AdminTemplateController@callSessionData')->name('uploadprogress');
```

My controller function

```
public function callSessionData(Request $request){
    $key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") . "myForm";
    print_r($_SESSION);

    if (!empty($_SESSION[$key])) {
        $current = $_SESSION[$key]["bytes_processed"];
        $total = $_SESSION[$key]["content_length"];
        echo $current < $total ? ceil($current / $total * 100) : 100;
    }
    else {
        echo 100;
    }
}
```

I've asked more people before and they don't seem to know the issue either, so if someone could help me with this issue I would me more than happy.

Comment: Read this before asking https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session

Answer (score 0):

a couple of things, in your ajax you shouldn't use php why don't you select the route already created in your form, it would be way more clean.

Maybe it returns nothing because this is not how you should access SESSION on laravel.

You should do it like this:

```
$yourSessionArray = $request->session()->get('key');
```

Please read about how to use [SESSION with laravel on their docs.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session)

Answer (score -1):

In Url use `url: "{{route('/uploadprogress')}}",` and in Route use `Route::get()` not `Route::post()` like:

```
Route::get('/uploadprogress', 'AdminTemplateController@callSessionData')->name('uploadprogress');
```

and in Ajax use:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/uploadprogress",
    data: {
        "data": $('#myForm').serialize(),
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
    },
    success: function() 
    {
        console.log("Geodata sent");
    }
});
```

Comment: @GaimZz why won't this work and what's problem with a little javascript in a view?

Comment: @Loek I expressed myself wrongly because it indeed works and the problem is about his session but just felt like needing to say something about this answer. which I think shouldn't be marked as positive, anyway deleted my comment X)